# Keycloak: how to set audience on returned token

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am writing an application in which my end-user code will obtain a Keycloak token with the 'password' grant type.

When I do this, I get back a token where the 'audience' is set to the local hostname of the keycloak server.

The [package I am using to authorize requests](https://github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware) with a bearer token validates the audience as part of token validation.

Because my keycloak server may one day be part of a cluster, returning the local node name of the server in the 'aud' field is problematic.

My code has no other use for the audience field. Is there an easy way to hardcode the 'aud' field of the JWT? I did see some [documentation in section 12 of the server administration guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#audience-support) on this, but I don't have the mental capacity to unwind what it's saying. Is there a "For Dummies" version of this text?

Comment: Hi, firstly if you are writing a new application you should not use the Password Grant type. This flow is obsolete and might not be supported anymore in a near future (cf. https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/). Secondly the audience is an additional protection that you should care about. It should not be dismissed too quickly. Finally my guess is that the content of your 'aud' field is the client name/id, right? (not the local node name). Can you confirm? It can be changed anyway easily via Global or Client Scope(s)/Mappers. You can define a specific audience per clusterized application